# Find number of non edge-intersecting shortest paths

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory, shortest-path

Given a weighted unoriented graph, start and finish vertices, I need to find number of exactly equal(in sum of weights) shortest paths that **do not intersect at any edge**.

I tried to use the Ford-Fulkerson's algorithm  here but it gives only the potential maximum number and does not find shortest paths.

Use of Dijkstra's algorithm  to find a path during Ford-Fulkerson does not help either since it may find path with one or more edges that connects paths in optimal solution.

As far as I see, there are some answers to a similar problems but with an unweighted and oriented graphs. I guess I need some kind of brute force method that will remove edges in some order. Or may be there is a known way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Edit 1: here is the graph that shows an example of Dijkstra's going the wrong way. The red edge (most likely) will be found 1st and it will make optimal solution impossible. I see the goal of algorithm is to remove somehow all the red edges and do what Vedang Mehta suggested

[image: Example graph]

Comment: @NicoSchertler: In the OP's example graph, there are 3 shortest paths: 0-1-4-5-6, 0-1-3-6 and 0-2-3-6.  The first and last are edge-disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first calculate dis[u] := length of shortest path from start to u.

Then we construct a direct graph(flow network) G' from dis[] and G:

check every edge(u,v) in G

```
if dis[u] = dis[v] + weight(u,v) then add a direct edge (u->v) to G'(capacities 1)

if dis[v] = dis[u] + weight(u,v) then add a direct edge (v->u) to G'(capacities 1)
```

The maximum number of non edge-intersecting shortest paths is just

**the maximum flow from start vertex to finish vertex on G'.**

Proof of Correctness

obvious.

Here is an implementation

http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/latest-svn/a00238.html

Comment: Thank you, it finally works! Well, in theory. Now I just need to make my Ford-Fulkerson not to find the red edges during flow calculations. But that's a different story.